# Как можно ускорить алгоритм?

Tags: delphi, инспекция-кода, delphi-7, delphi-xe

**Не устраивает** только одно - **скорость работы алгоритма**, как можно ускорить алгоритм в этом коде (**Может из за того что использую AssignFile ?**).:

Может использовать **TStreamReader** (но с ним работать не пробовала) или другой метод. Кто что подскажет?

```
procedure TForm1.BitBtn3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  F1, F2: TextFile;
  S, Name: String;
  k1, k2: string;
  z, m: integer;
begin

  // Открываем диалог
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    // Открываем файл
    AssignFile(F1, OpenDialog1.FileName);
    Reset(F1);
    While not EOF(F1) do
    Begin
      // Читаем
      Readln(F1, S);
      // Переменные
      z := Pos('+', S) or Pos('-', S);
      m := Pos('№', S);
      // Формируем имя каждого файла
      Name := Copy(S, m, z - m) + '.txt';
      // Открываем файл
      AssignFile(F2, Name);
      IF FileExists(Name) then
        Append(F2)
      else
        Rewrite(F2);
      // Запись
      Writeln(F2, S);
      // Закрываем файл
      CloseFile(F2);

    End;
    // Закрываем файл
    CloseFile(F1);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Стоит почитать описание метки "инспекция-кода" (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0/info) и дополнить вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаёте кучу однострочных текстовых файлов. Метод доступа к файлам тут роли не играет, т.к. всё ограничено файловыми операциями нахождения-создания-закрытия файла, а они существенно отличаться не будут.

А вот нужны ли Вам эти однострочные файлы в большом (судя по тревоге о быстродействии) количестве - это вопрос...

Comment: Спасибо за комментирования данной темы. Тут как раз они и нужны. Получается выхода с данной ситуации нет и какой бы метод не выбрать , все равно скорость не увеличится ?

Comment: Да, при создании большого количества файлов - существенно не изменится.

Comment: Возможно, поможет использование SSD. Если файлы часто повторяются, то поможет реорганизация для сокращения количества открытий/закрытий.

Comment: Что Вы делаете с этими файлами? Нельзя ли использовать строки из большого текста напрямую, или сторонней программе нужен именно маленький файлик с предопределённым именем на каждый случай?

Comment: @MBo, напрямую я то знаю как сделать, это не проблема была. Но тут сторонней программе именно нужно файлик с предопределённым именем на каждый случай. В этом и суть загвоздки.

Comment: Увы, тогда ничего не поделаешь.

Comment: @MBo, Пробовала еще с буфером поиграться. Ничего не помогло, спасибо всем и Вам за помошь!

Comment: нет, никакой буфер для малых файлов не поможет. Неотъемлемая часть задачи - поиск имени в таблице размещения файлов (где могут быть десятки тысяч имён), поиск места и выделение кластера длиной минимум 512 байт, запись его координат в таблицу размещения. На этом фоне запись 50 байтов вашей строки в файл - ничто.